# Custom error messages for login and lost password forms

Tags: wp-login-form

When a user enters wrong username/email or password in the login form, I want them to see "Invalid username/email or password." error message. That's easy to do with the following code:

```
add_filter('login_errors', create_function('$a', "return '<b>Error:</b> Invalid username/email or password.';"));
```

But with this code, the error message is displayed also in the lost password form. And the part with the **wrong password doesn't make sense here**, because you enter only username or email.

I found this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/password-reset-message-if-user-is-invalid/ but since I don't code, I don't know how to use it or even if it's possible.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `create_function` will generate errors on newer versions of PHP, you should switch away from that style of code, though by using `create_function` you're actually overcomplicating how it works and making things harder

Comment: Check out my answer. It will resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. You can add custom error messages based on different error codes.

```
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'custom_login_errros_callback' );

function custom_login_errros_callback( $error ) {
    global $errors;
    $err_codes = $errors->get_error_codes();

    if ( in_array( 'invalid_username', $err_codes ) ) {
        $error = '<b>Error:</b> Invalid username/email or password.';
    }

    if ( in_array( 'incorrect_password', $err_codes ) ) {
        $error = '<b>Error:</b> Invalid username/email or password.';
    }

    if ( in_array( 'empty_username', $err_codes ) ) {
        $error = '<b>Error:</b> Invalid username/email or password.';
    }

    if ( in_array( 'empty_password', $err_codes ) ) {
        $error = '<b>Error:</b> Invalid username/email or password.';
    }

    return $error;
}
```